# Accessing fields from an model associated to a django user in template

Tags: python, django, model, django-templates

I have a model `User_Details` associated with each Django User. It has a field named `mobile_number`. I want to access the `mobile_number` in my template. I am trying `request.user.User_Details.mobile_number` but it's not working. Is it the right way? If not, then how should I go about it?

Comment: We can't tell, because you haven't included the models in your question. Changing it to `request.user.user_details.mobile_number` might work.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Are you seriously asking why we need details of the models you're asking about?

Comment: Because the answer depends on the foreign key, not just the name of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I am assuming index.html as template, which is properly set in urls.py):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    user_details = User_Details.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username))

    context = RequestContext(request, {'mobile_no':user_details.mobile_number,}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Works if you have a user object (django.contrib.auth.models) in your User_Details Model

```
class User_Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(...
```

Then in your index.html or whatever template use

```
{{mobile_no}}
```

to display the information

Comment: I know this method but I wanted to do this using `request.user` directly in my template.

Comment: you have to access the database on server side, meaning you have to get the request sent to the django backend. what do you mean "directly in template"? the HTTP authentication model does not know anything about your User_Details. They are stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

Its defficult to tell without looking at your model but I guess you can use `related_name` in the `OneToOneField` and access it directly.

```
class User_Details(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="detail")
   mobile_number = models.CharField(...
```

then
`request.user.detail.mobile_number` to access it.
Hope it helps